# ¿Cómo puedo insertar múltiples registros al mismo tiempo?

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Saludos, tengo un script que recibe múltiples datos de un formulario pero solo inserta una sola línea de registros, aquí debajo está el form que envia los datos:**

```html
<form method="post" action="row2.php" autocomplete="off">
 <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

 <INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

 <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
  <TR>
   <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></TD>
   <TD><INPUT type="text" name="txt[]"/></TD>
   <TD>
    <SELECT name="country[]">
     <OPTION value="in">India</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="de">Germany</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="fr">France</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="us">United States</OPTION>
     <OPTION value="ch">Switzerland</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
   </TD>
  </TR>
 </TABLE>
 <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

**Y este es el script que recibe y guarda los datos:**

```html
$chkbox = $_POST['chk'];
$txtbox = $_POST['txt'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
foreach($txtbox as $a => $b){
  echo "$chkbox[$a]  -  $txtbox[$a]  -  $country[$a] <br />";
}
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO country (text, country)
VALUES ('$txtbox[$a]', '$country[$a]')";
```

Al momento de imprimir las variables con los valores no presenta ningún tipo de problema, pero al momento de insertarlos en la tabla, solo inserta la primera fila del registro creado en el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu SQL tamblién debe estar en el loop para recorrer todos los campos, por ejemplo:

```
foreach($txtbox as $a => $b){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO country (text, country)
            VALUES ('$txtbox[$a]', '$country[$a]')";
    // Añade la ejecución de tu SQL
}
```

Comment: gracias @DEV_NIX